# Can you overload a global operator in a .hpp file?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I wrote an overload for + to add two `vector<double>`:

```
vector<double> operator+(vector<double> v, vector<double> u)
{
    int n = (v.size()<u.size()) ? v.size() : u.size();
    vector<double> w;
    for (int j = 0; j<n; ++j)
        w.push_back(v[j] + u[j]);
    return w;
};
```

If I put in a .cpp file it's fine. But if I put in a .hpp file it generates a lot of errors related to "xutils" system file. Is this normal?

Comment: How are the errors related to "xutils" system file?

Comment: Setting a global standard function in a header which acts on standard containers of built in types is dangerous. What if 2 libraries tried to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *define* a global function in a header file, you have to make it inline.

```
inline vector<double> operator+(vector<double> v, vector<double> u)
{
   ...
}
```

You can however *declare* it in a header, then define it in one cpp file.

```
//x.hpp
vector<double> operator+(vector<double> v, vector<double> u);

//x.cpp
vector<double> operator+(vector<double> v, vector<double> u)
{
    int n = (v.size()<u.size()) ? v.size() : u.size();
    vector<double> w;
    for (int j = 0; j<n; ++j)
        w.push_back(v[j] + u[j]);
    return w;
} // No need for a semi colon here
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to define a global `operator+` to add two `std::vector`s STL has a facility for this. Defining global operators can really mess things up and cause conflicts. You could use [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/):

```
std::vector<double> a {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
std::vector<double> b {5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0};
std::vector<double> res(a.size());

std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::begin(res), std::plus<double>());
```

[*LIVE DEMO*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e32f2414014a5683)

Answer (score 0):

Change the prototype to

`inline vector<double> operator+(const vector<double>& v, const vector<double>& u)`

`inline` allows the function body to be written in the header.

Passing the parameters by constant reference is unnecessary for compilation but *will* prevent value copies from being taken, so giving you a performance gain without loss of program stability.

(It's unwise to have a function like this at header scope though as it could pollute your code base. Also, the implementation looks incorrect: you are not including excess elements from the larger vector in your sum).